# Common Lisp: first returns first, but last returns a list of last -- huh?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm not getting this first/last thing in Common-Lisp.  Yes, I see how it works, but I don't get WHY it works that way.

Basically, to get the first item in a list, I can use `(first mylist)`.  However, if I want the last item, `(last mylist)` doesn't give me that; instead, it gives me a list containing the last item in my list!

(I'm using Clozure-CL, which has a few other oddities that seem like bugs to me but, since I'm a Lisp-n00b, I'm trying not to fall for the old "the interpreter is broken!" trick :) )

So, for example:

```
? (setq x '((1 2) (a b)))
=> ((1 2) (A B))

? (first x)
=> (1 2)  ; as expected

? (last x)
=> ((A B))  ; why a list with my answer in it?!

? (first (last x))
=> '(A B)  ; This is the answer I'd expect from plain-old (last x)
```

Can someone help me understand why last does this?  Am I using these items incorrectly?  Is `first` really the odd-ball?!

Thanks!

Comment: Doing '('(1 2) '(a b)) is not what you actually mean, I guess. Use '((1 2) (a b)) instead. What you wrote creates he following list: ((quote (1 2)) (quote (a b))). Here the two 'quote's are not interpreted as the special operator you probably meant but just plain old symbols who happen to have the same name. To see what I mean evaluate (first (first '('(1 2) '(a b)))) in your REPL. It should return QUOTE.

Comment: Thomas: you are correct.  Source edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Common Lisp `last` is supposed to return a list, from the [documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_last.htm):

```
last list &optional n => tail
list---a list, which might be a dotted list but must not be a circular list.
n---a non-negative integer. The default is 1.
tail---an object.
```

> last returns the last n conses (not the last n elements) of list. If list is (), last returns ().

For example:

```
(setq x (list 'a 'b 'c 'd))
(last x) =>  (d)
```

And yes, this is counterintuitive. In other flavors of Lisp it works as the name suggests, for example in Racket (a Scheme dialect):

```
(define x '((1 2) (a b)))
(first x) => '(1 2)
(last x) => '(a b)

(define x (list 'a 'b 'c 'd))
(last x) =>  'd
```

Comment: Ok, accepted, and thanks for the other examples.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't completely missing some critical point, as the first/last mismatch seems so inelegant compared to the rest of the language (although Kaz's point about get[f]/set[f] is pretty funny, too :) )

Answer (score 8):

Returning the last element is not very useful except to access the last element; returning the last cons lets you do something like this:

```
(let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
  (setf (cdr (last x)) '(4))
  x)

=> '(1 2 3 4)
```

while you can still access the last element as `(car (last x))`.

Comment: Ok, that's useful.  I guess I just wanted to verify that I wasn't totally missing the boat, since it seems **so** counter-intuitive that first/last isn't a matching pair.

Answer (score 5):

Common Lisp's misnamed function [`last`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_last.htm) gives you the last **cons**.

It should probably be called `tail`, as there is a function [`tailp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_ldiffc.htm), but my guess is that this name stuck for historical/compatibility reasons.

Generally, it gives you the *nth* tail of a list, or the *nth* cons before the end of the list.

Answer (score 4):

This is just the way it is. `first` and `last` are not a complementary pair of operations. `last` is more closely related to `rest` and `nthcdr`. There is also `butlast` which constructs a new list that omits the last item from the given list.

`first` versus `last` is nothing compared to how `get` and `getf` have nothing to do with `set` and `setf`.

Comment: LOL: first vs last <=> get[f] vs set[f] -- yeah!  It's like they made it intentionally to mess with n00bs' heads!